# Can we express a real number as the limit of a series of fractions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can every real number $r\in (x,y) $ be assigned a sequence of negative and positive signs $\{\sigma_k\}\equiv\{-1,1,1,-1,...\}$ such that

$$r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sigma_k}{2^k}(y-x)$$

$\textbf{Simpler Question}$(set  $x=0$, $y=1$): can you get to any real number in $(0,1)$ by iteratively adding or subtracting higher and higher powers of $1/2$?

Comment: Sure, take binary expansion, and whenever you have a segment of zeros obtain it by subtracting, e.g. $1/2+0/2^2+0/2^3+1/2^4=1/2+1/2^2-1/2^3-1/2^4$.

Comment: Whoops that was dumb - and this works for any x,y?

Comment: nvm I get the picture...

Answer (score 0):

When $(x,y)=(0,1)$, start from the usual binary expansion $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n\frac1{2^n}$ of every number $x$ in $(0,1)$, where each $b_n$ is in $\{0,1\}$, and consider $\frac12+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(2b_n-1)\frac1{2^{n+1}}$.

This yields $r=\frac12(1+x)$ in $(0,1)$ with $\sigma_1=1$ and $\sigma_{n+1}=2b_n-1$ for every $n\geqslant1$.